# Non Unique one to one relationship Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

Hi im using AspNetCore with entity framework. I need a way to perform a non unique one to one relationship between two tables.

I have a person

```
public class Person {

   public int PersonId {get;set;}
   public int? LocationId {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set}
}

public class Location {

   public int LocationId {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set}
}
```

I want to reuse the LocationId within the person table but im getting the following error

```
SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Person' with unique index 'IX_Persons_LocationId'. The duplicate key value is (3).
The statement has been terminated.
```

I considered using a map table between them but the LocationId will still appear multiple times.

I've looked at defining a builder within OnModelCreating, but i cant find a IsUnique() extension method relating to a foreign key just the primary key

UPDATE

The above model works fine for the first person that i create, but fails when i try and create a second person with the same location as the first person.

The error is saying i can only use a location once within the LocationId field in the person table

Comment: "non unique one to one relationship" there's no such thing.  That would simply be one-to-many.

Comment: I was replying then in realised my mistake. Thankyou.